# ¿Llamar a una clase desde JTextField?

Tags: java, clase, jtextfield

Es posible llamar a una clase desde JTextField? por ejemplo yo tengo un JTextField y un boton. Tengo varias clases "Manzana" "Pera" "Banana" etc si el usuario coloca "Manzana" en el JTextField y le da al boton, mostraria en un label las propiedades de la clase. No quiero hacer un if ya que son muchas clases, tampoco quiero usar un JComboBox o un JList.

Agradezco la ayuda

Comment: Me temo que te guste o no, en algún sitio tendrás que poner un if que identifique la cadena introducida y en función de esa comparación del if, construya cada uno de los objetos de cada clase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver si este ejemplo te puede ayudar:

```
package ejmostrarcamposclase;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class EjMostrarCamposClase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Manzana manzana1 =new Manzana(10);
        Pera pera1 =new Pera();

        System.out.println("Propiedades de clase pasándole objeto: "+pera1.getClass().getSimpleName());

        Field[] camposPera =getCamposDeClase(pera1);
        int longitCamposPera =camposPera.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < longitCamposPera; i++) {
            System.out.println("Nombre atributo: "+camposPera[i].getName());
            camposPera[i].setAccessible(true);//necesario cuando los atributos son privados
            System.out.println("Valor atributo: "+getValorCampoDeClase(camposPera[i], pera1));
        }

        System.out.println("Propiedades de clase pasándole nombre de clase:");

        System.out.println("La clase es: "+getClase("Manzana").getSimpleName());


        Field[] camposDe =getCamposDeClase("Manzana");
        int longitCamposDe =camposDe.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < longitCamposDe; i++) {
            System.out.println("Nombre atributo: "+camposDe[i].getName());
            camposDe[i].setAccessible(true);//necesario cuando los atributos son privados
            System.out.println("Valor atributo: "+getValorCampoDeClase(camposDe[i], manzana1));         
        }   
    }

    private static Field[] getCamposDeClase(Object obj){

        return obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    }
    private static Object getValorCampoDeClase(Field campoClase, Object instancia){

        try {
            //este método te obliga a capturar estas excepciones, por eso el try-catch
            return campoClase.get(instancia);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EjMostrarCamposClase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EjMostrarCamposClase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static final String paqueteClase ="ejmostrarcamposclase.";

    private static Field[] getCamposDeClase(String nombreClase){

        try {
            //este método te obliga a capturar la excepción, por eso el try-catch
            return Class.forName(paqueteClase+nombreClase).getDeclaredFields();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EjMostrarCamposClase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
    private static Class getClase(String nombreClase){

        try {
            return Class.forName(paqueteClase+nombreClase);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EjMostrarCamposClase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
class Manzana{
    private int a;
    private String b;
    //con constructor para asignar valor para luego mostrar
    public Manzana(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
class Pera{
    private static final double c =5.99;//con constante de clase para mostrar valor
    private int d;
}
class Banana{
    private float e;
    private String [] f;
}
```

Pero faltaría controlar que el usuario no ingrese una clase que no existe, o bien capturar la/s excepción/es que se lanza.

A ver si alguien puede ayudar con esto último.

Comment: En parte el problema esta solucionado, digo en parte porque se me complica a la hora de obtener los valores en getValorCampoDeClase() porque yo necesitaría obtener los valores para unos cuantos objetos 194 para ser exactos el tema es que debería hacer una instancia para esos 194 objetos, y eso es lo que quiero reducir, nose como harán los demas en estos casos, talvez solamente utilizando 194 ifs? :/ no me lo creo. Ademas de estar el problema de si no ingresa el nombre de una clase como bien dices.Te agradezco de igual manera ya que por lo menos pude obtener algo de info al respecto

Comment: Claro. Si esas clases llegaran a tener todos campos de clase, o sea estáticos, no hace falta crear objeto y a `getValorCampoDeClase` le pasas `null` al parámetro de instancia. Probá con `Banana`, declara ambos atributos estáticos y los campos los pedis así: `getValorCampoDeClase(camposBanana[i], null))`. Pero dudo que sean todos los campos de todas las clases estáticos